Tracking Views for Iframe on External Website with Google Analytics
We produce a calendar that is syndicated to other sites with a script (iframe). How can we track this traffic in our Google Analytics account? I need to know the page views for each script.
I can't find this data in any of the reports. Am I overlooking something?
